# Spinner isn't working in onEndReachedThreshold Flatlist

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, infinite-scroll, react-native-flatlist

This is my flatlist code:

```
<FlatList style={styles.scrollView} onScroll={(event) => this.handleOnScroll(event) } scrollEventThrottle={16} ref='scrollUp'
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    renderItem={({item}) =>(
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer} onScroll={(event) => this.handleOnScroll(event) } scrollEventThrottle={16} ref='scrollUp'>
            {this._getHomeComponent(item)}
        </ScrollView>
    )}
    onEndReached={this._handleLoadMore}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
    refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
            title=""
            tintColor="#86bc40"
            titleColor="#86bc40"
        />
    }
/>
```

So i want to show spinner when i pull up at the end of the content, here is my _handleLoadMore function:

```
_handleLoadMore = () => {
    return(
        <Spinner/>
    )
}
```

I've tried pull up in the end of the content but the spinner doesn't appear, what's the problem? i'm using android device

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a different Flatlist property called **ListFooterComponent** :

```
<FlatList style={styles.scrollView} onScroll={(event) => this.handleOnScroll(event) } scrollEventThrottle={16} ref='scrollUp'
data={this.state.data}
keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
renderItem={({item}) =>(
    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer} onScroll={(event) => this.handleOnScroll(event) } scrollEventThrottle={16} ref='scrollUp'>
        {this._getHomeComponent(item)}
    </ScrollView>
)}
onEndReached={this._handleLoadMore}
onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
        title=""
        tintColor="#86bc40"
        titleColor="#86bc40"
    />
}
ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
/>
```

and your renderFooter might look like this:

```
renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.showSpinner) return null

    return (
      <Spinner/>
    )
}
```

**onEndReached** should be used to load more data into your this.state.data and to set this.state.showSpinner to true. After more data is loaded, turn showSpinner to false and the footer should disappear.